# erlang zero dependencies installer for Debian and Ubuntu

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

In order to ease the installation process of [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html), I want to use a simple, zero dependencies installer for erlang.
There is a great project on Github from the guys at RabbitMQ - [erlang-rpm](https://github.com/rabbitmq/erlang-rpm), but this is RPM only.

I'm aware of [erlang-solutions](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/), but it not a single, no dependencies installer.

**EDIT**: Adding some context here. I need this to be able to prepare a simple, offline install to my app, which needs RabbitMQ. Offline means NO access to internet for downloading dependencies.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can add some context about _why_ you need a zero-dep installer and then you can get a better answer than "no".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Zero-dependency Erlang Ubuntu/Debian for RabbitMQ.

But the Erlang Solution package can be installed easily.

We built the Centos package because the dependencies are hard to install on Centos (if you don't want to use the `epel`)

If you want to create an offline setup, you can do it like for other packages (https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline). Or you can create your own package by building Erlang from source code.

**Note** also RabbitMQ has dependencies as `socat`

Comment: What if I want to support an offline install. I need to collect all dependencies beforehand? There are a million packages...

Comment: In the same way you'd do it for other packages (http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline). 

Or you can create your package by build the Erlang from source code.

Comment: That's acceptable. Can you edit your answer to add this and I'll accept it?